# WPF Listview Textbox Highlight

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a listview which binds the customers informations. I highlight the listview items by typing in a textbox. For example, when I type "PET" into the textbox then it highlights the "PET"s in the listview items. It works and highlights.

But after that when I click on the highlighted item it gives an error. But it is interesting when I click on a free place in the listview item it works. For example, it highlighted PETER HEINZ. IF I click on to PETER or HEINZ it gives error. But, if I click on the space between PETER HEINZ it works. What a error is this? The error message is

**System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message="'System.Windows.Documents.Run' is not a Visual or Visual3D."**

The source code is below:

```
private void HighlightText(Object itx)
    {
 if (itx != null)
        {
            if (itx is TextBlock)
            {
                Regex regex = new Regex("(" + textBox1.Text + ")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                TextBlock tb = itx as TextBlock;
                if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0)
                {
                    string str = tb.Text;
                    tb.Inlines.Clear();
                    tb.Inlines.Add(str);
                    return;
                }
                string[] substrings = regex.Split(tb.Text);
                tb.Inlines.Clear();
                foreach (var item in substrings)
                {
                    if (regex.Match(item).Success)
                    {
                        Run runx = new Run(item);
                        runx.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
                        tb.Inlines.Add(runx);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tb.Inlines.Add(item);
                    }
                }
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(itx as DependencyObject); i++)
                {
                    HighlightText(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(itx as DependencyObject, i));
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your code? Did you check what line shows the error? [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: "it gives error"  what error?  Simply telling us the exception type would allow us to help you much easier.

Comment: @Blachshma I tried debugging and looked to lines. But the error is only when you click on the highlighted textblock. That's why I couldnt understand it.

Comment: @BillTarbell System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message="'System.Windows.Documents.Run' is not a Visual or Visual3D."

Comment: @Blachshma Run runx = new Run(item);

Comment: It seems unlikely that this is the line causing the problem. Have you tried debugging it? If you have, how many times do you hit the breakpoint on that line before this happens?

Comment: @Blachshma i think tb.inlines.clear() is the problem. IS there any other methods to clear the textbox instead of tb.inlines.clear?

Comment: What makes you think THAT line is the problem now?

Comment: this codes show me the typed text's higlight in the listivew. Just same as when you make CNTRL+F then you highlight the typed text in the browser as highlighted. That just like that but when I click on the highlighted text block then it gives me the error that I indicate above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a revisement.  Can you paste it over yours and see if it works better in your application?

key points:

- Added protection to not let non-visual objects make it to the GetChild recursion
- Added check for textbox1 being empty
- trivial: moved tb.inlines.clear to reduce code repitition
- trivial: inverted itx null check to reduce nesting

.

```
private void HighlightText(Object itx)
{
    //safety checks
    if (itx == null)
        return;        
    if (String.isNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)
        return; //just in case the box is empty
    if (! (itx is Visual || itx is System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Visual3D)
        return;  //prevent from getting children on non-visual element

    if (itx is TextBlock)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("(" + textBox1.Text + ")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        TextBlock tb = itx as TextBlock;
        tb.Inlines.Clear();
        if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            string str = tb.Text;
            tb.Inlines.Add(str);
            return;
        }
        string[] substrings = regex.Split(tb.Text);
        foreach (var item in substrings)
        {

            if (!regex.Match(item).Success)
            {
                Run runx = new Run(item);
                runx.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
                tb.Inlines.Add(runx);
            }
            else
            {
                tb.Inlines.Add(item);
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(itx as DependencyObject); i++)
        {
            HighlightText(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(itx as DependencyObject, i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, providing some safety checks was the best i could do with the information provided.  I suggest providing a small working sample if you would like direct debugging support.